# How to launch a oneshot systemd service on the failure of another systemd service

Tags: systemd

I would like to launch a native application (c++) when a systemd service fails. There are many articles online which describe something similar: launching a shell script on failure. Some do it from the same service, others use another service. I tried to lauch the native application from another service.

appServer.service

```
[Unit]
Description=app server
OnFailure=appServerCrashAlerter.service
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/john/Documents/app
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
KillMode=process
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

appServerCrashAlerter.service

```
[Unit]
Description=app server crash alerter
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/john/Documents/alerter
User=nobody
Group=systemd-journal
```

The alerter service is not launched on the failure of the first service. I can't enable the second service but when I start it, the application is launched properly. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4).

Comment: If you try having your service’s OnFailure directly call the c++ program, does that work? For completion’s sake, you have tested that your c++ runs as expected outside of the issue with trying to run it on failure of a systemd service?

Comment: Calling the c++ application directly onFailure does not work. Yes The application works as expected when the service is started explicitly (sudo systemctl start appServerCrashAlerter.service). The c++ alerter application only prints a message for now (iostream).